# I want to put text file to table in php

Tags: php

I have a text file:

> [{"title": "...", "Book": ["A", "B"]}]

How can I read it and put into table using **php**??

Comment: file_get_contents()

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What is the table structure where you want to insert the data in?

Comment: My table structure: Course, Time, Room, Professor, Number of student

Comment: are you getting data as json format ?

Comment: no, as text file. Is there any way that i can read to table in php?

Comment: How do you do it?  With code.  Can't do it?  Do research.  Can't do that?  Hire a developer.  You are not using StackOverflow properly.

Comment: Parse the text to get the fields you need and insert it into the table ;)
If you want someone to write the code for you, hire someone.
If you want to ask how to do a certain step, try asking a more specific question.

Comment: mickmackusa: You're totally right. I should hire a developer than to ask question. Thank so much for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this.

if you need to read a text file then use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.

```
<?php
$fh     =   file_get_contents('text.txt');
$table  =   json_decode($fh);
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($table as $val){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $val->title; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $val->Book[0]; ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**NOTE** Set your table head as per your need.

Comment: OP wants to read text from text file. Your answer does not answer that.

Comment: It works. Except time[0], show only WS1.. btw, thank you very much

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just a beginner one. I will work hard more. Thank you!